# Matplotlib: Set the animation.rc parameter

Tags: matplotlib

While plotting a large animation in Matplotlib, I received the warning:

> Animation size has reached 20997590 bytes, exceeding the limit of
>   20971520.0. If you're sure you want a larger animation embedded, set the animation.embed_limit rc parameter to a larger value (in MB). This
>   and further frames will be dropped.

Does anyone know how to set this parameter?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Aha:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
```